# Octave plot is not correctly printed in pdfcairo

Tags: plot, octave

I'm trying to `subplot` my data, but printing in PDF brings results I can't use: Title and x-axis title are cut (and the legend's box is covered by the graph, but I can handle this with other positions). I have to use gnuplot and pdfcairo because other seup isn't working with special characters, umlaut, etc.

```
clear;clc;close all;clf;clear all;
graphics_toolkit("gnuplot")

    x = 0:.1:10;
    y1 = exp(-x).*sin(x);
    y2 = exp(x);

h=figure(1);

subplot(2,1,1);
    plot(x,y1)
        h1 = plot(x,y1);
        set(h1,'LineWidth',4)
        set(gca,'FontSize',32)
        set(gca,'FontName','Times')
        set(get(gca,'Ylabel'),'String','TTEST test \rho \rightarrow','FontWeight','Bold','FontSize',32)
        set(get(gca,'Xlabel'),'String','abc / - \rightarrow','FontWeight','Bold','FontSize',32)
        legend({
          'h_{ref}(t)'
          },"location", 'northeast');
          title('TITLE')

        l1 = legend;
        set(l1,'FontName','Times')

  subplot(2,1,2);  
        h2 = plot(x,y2);
        set(h2,'LineWidth',4)
        set(gca,'FontSize',32)
        set(gca,'FontName','Times')
        set(get(gca,'Ylabel'),'String','TTEST test \rho \rightarrow','FontWeight','Bold','FontSize',32)
        set(get(gca,'Xlabel'),'String','agc / -\rightarrow','FontWeight','Bold','FontSize',32)
        legend({
          'h_{ref}(t)'
          },"location", 'northeast');
        l2 = legend;
        set(l2,'FontName','Times')
print ('title_axis.pdf', '-dpdfcairo', '-S1000,600');
```

Comment: If a question doesn't specifically involve MATLAB, please only use the Octave tag. Despite the languages being syntactically similar, this question is about plotting libraries and exporting, which is likely to be Octave specific - algorithms, code errors etc would be more relevant for using both tags.

Comment: What is your goal at the end? Do you want to include the generated plot into a LaTeX documenta?

Comment: what version of octave and system are you using ?

Comment: @Wolfie: I'll do this, thanks for the hint!

Comment: @matzeri: I'm using Octave 4.4.1 in Kubunt 18.04

Comment: @Andy: Yes, the result should be a latex file, but for this I'm working with pdf's, so I tried the pdfcairo here.

Comment: If you are using pdflatex I would suggest to plot as eps and use psfrag.